# Why does the if loop in this function return the wrong statement? (from fCC Profile Lookup challenge)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I was doing the freeCodeCamp Profile Lookup challenge, but I'm confused as to why the `return "No such contact` has to be outside of the for loop. In my first attempt, I had it written as an `else` statement after the first if statement, but that would return "No such contact" instead of the property's value.

I tried looking at other threads about this challenge and I know it has something to do with letting the for loop run all iterations before the return statement, *but why does this need to happen, and why is it causing the code to not work?*

Here is the version that I'm talking about (also, I know that I am missing the "No such property" return; at this point, I hadn't reached it yet):

```
function lookUpProfile(name,prop) {
  for(let n = 0; n<contacts.length; n++ ){
    if(name == contacts[n].firstName && contacts[n].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return contacts[n][prop]
    } else {
      return "No such contact"
    }
  } 
}
```

When I do `console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"))`, the result is "No such contact", but without the else statement, it returns the correct value, which is "Vos".

Here is the correct version after I fixed it, as well as the full code from the site:

````
// Setup
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  let n = 0; // index of contacts array
  for(n = 0; n<contacts.length; n++ ){
    if(name == contacts[n].firstName){
      return contacts[n][prop] || "No such property"
    } 
  } 
  return "No such contact"

  // Only change code above this line
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");```
````

Answer (score 0):

That is because inside the `for` loop in the each iteration the `if` is checked and when it is not matching it is going to `else` block. In the `else block there is` return` statement. So the loops is stoping its execution there and existing the function without further iteration.

```js
const contacts = [{
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (let n = 0; n < contacts.length; n++) {
    if (name === contacts[n].firstName && contacts[n].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[n][prop]
    }
  }

  return "No such contact"

}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"))
```